# dropdown on menu hover

Tags: html, css

i have a menu that when i hover has a drop down i follow [this](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-hide-dropdown-on-mouse-hover)
 and [this](http://code-tricks.com/simple-css-drop-down-menu/) but unfortunately im getting different result than expected..im getting list but it is displayed as line horizontally and not vertically like the example here is the code i added to make the drop down

```
css
ul # menu li  ul .submenu{
    display:none;
}
ul # menu li : hover ul .submenu{
    display:block;
}
```

here is the html

```
<div id="menu">
                        <ul id="menu-list">
                            <li id=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li id="">
                                <a href="#">Menu</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li id=""><a href="#">Menu</a></li>

                            <li id=""><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                            <li id=""><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/57wuy/)

Just the small change. Made `UL id = "menu"`

```
                       <ul id="menu">
                        <li id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="townoffice">
                            <a href="#">Menu</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="busines"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>

                        <li id="residents"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li id="tourists"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: this code from the example what im trying to find out is what is wrong with mine i didnt put all the code in because i dont need them all..all i want is the dropdown part which i can get with the code that used to make it work \

Comment: What I did is just removed the Div Tag from your code and Added id=menu to UL tag. And that worked :)

Comment: i see let me try it sir

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav" class="sixteen columns">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="asia.html">Asia</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Korea</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="europe.html">Europe</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Italy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    width:800px;
    margin:30px 50px;
   padding: 0;
    float:left;
}
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding:0 10px;
   background-color:#367FB3;
    color:white;
}


#nav li a:hover {
   background-color:#52baff;
    color:#fff;
}
//daf adf
/*--temp--*/
 #nav ul ul li {
    clear:left;
}
#nav ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:14em;
    top:0;
}
#nav ul ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    color: #242424;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
/*--end temp--*/
 #nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    color: #242424;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#367FB3;
}
#nav a:active {
    color:#367FB3;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 14em;
    /* Width to help Opera out */
    background-color:transparent;
    z-index:666;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px -10px;
    padding:0px;
}
#nav li:hover ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#nav li ul li:hover ul {
    display:block
}
#nav li:hover li, #nav li.hover li {
    float: none;
    line-height:30px;
}
#nav li:hover li a, #nav li.hover li a {
    background-color:#367FB3;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:"Lato" !important;
}
#nav li li a:hover {
    background-color:#52baff;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vD3/11/)**